# Nginx configuration is not starting a rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix, ubuntu, nginx

I am trying to config an amazon EC2. Ubuntu 14.04. I am getting this message on nginx access.log

```
2015/12/25 11:19:24 [error] 4403#0: *1 connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/apptest/shared/puma.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 109.67.134.46, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ubuntu/apptest/shared/puma.sock:/", host: "54.174.110.190"
```

**`My /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/apptest.conf` is**

```
upstream apptest {
    # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/home/ubuntu/apptest/shared/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /home/ubuntu/apptest/current/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @apptest;

    location @apptest {
        proxy_pass http://apptest;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

but when I run `**bundle exec puma -e production -b unix:///home/ubuntu/apptest/shared/puma.sock**` in the server

> [4328] Puma starting in cluster mode...
>
> [4328] * Version 2.15.3 (ruby 2.2.1-p85), codename: Autumn Arbor
>   Airbrush
>
> [4328] * Min threads: 1, max threads: 6
>
> [4328] * Environment: production
>
> [4328] * Process workers: 1
>
> [4328] * Phased restart available
>
> [4328] * Listening on unix:///home/ubuntu/apptest/shared/puma.sock

the website loads. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Puma will not be started automatically by Nginx. It has to be started on its own. There are some useful scripts in the official Puma [repository](https://github.com/puma/puma/tree/master/tools/jungle).

Comment: Awesome. That's exactly what I was looking for.